# Radiobutton not updating values when clicked in python with tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter, radio-button

This is my first attempt at a GUI. Right now I just want to be able to click a radiobutton and make it print the value I assigned to the button. However, `var.get()` isn't giving me anything. I tried it with `IntVar` (and had my values as 1 and 2 instead of "proton" and "electron") and `var.get()` would just give me 0. With `StringVar` it gives nothing (nothing prints when `choosecharge` is called by the radiobutton). I've tried reading stuff about radiobuttons and I wrote my code based on how I saw it done and it successfully creates the radiobuttons, but the whole point is to be able to use their values when clicked.

```
import tkinter as tk
def choosecharge():
  print(var.get())

root = tk.Tk()
var = tk.StringVar()
proton = tk.Radiobutton(root, text = "proton", variable = var, value = "proton", command = choosecharge)
proton.pack( )

electron = tk.Radiobutton(root, text="electron", variable = var, value= "electron", command = choosecharge)
electron.pack( )


root.mainloop()
```

Comment: When I run your code it prints the selected value each time I click on one of the radiobuttons. I don't see the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I have taken a slightly different approach to accomplish this task.

- I created a dictionary of the integer radiobutton values as key and
  the string that you wish to print as value.
- Used a label widget to print the string in the GUI

```py
import tkinter as tk

root = tk.Tk()

# define an IntVar
var = tk.IntVar()

# create a dictionary of key:value pair as radiobutton_value: str_name_to_print
values = {1: "proton", 2: "electron"}

# instantiate a label widget
lbl = tk.Label(root)

def choosecharge():
    # update the label widgets using the dictionary
    lbl.config(text=values[var.get()])

proton = tk.Radiobutton(root, text="proton", variable=var, value=1, command=choosecharge)
proton.pack(anchor=tk.W)

electron = tk.Radiobutton(root, text="electron", variable=var, value=2, command=choosecharge)
electron.pack(anchor=tk.W)

# pack the label widget below the two radiobuttons
lbl.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

**Screenshot**

[image] [image]

I have commented the lines in the code for better understanding. I hope this solution helps you.

Comment: Thank you!! I was able to make it do the thing!! :D